# How can I make the item header fit a multi-line text?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I want to use Draw.io for UML class diagrams but while autosize is generally useful, it doesn't work for item headers:

[image]

Trying to manually adjust the size of the header also appears somewhat unpredictable. Is there a way to do this more neatly? I've noticed if the text you enter is too long for the item width, auto-size doesn't address this either.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the orange diamond shape down to fit all text lines when e.g class shape is selected or just increase Header size when shape is selected in Property/Value on the right.

If you'd like to use autosize, try the following: type multiline text, click Property/Value on the right > Autosize and then modify text with e.g bold/italic/font size. The thing is that autosize is triggered by label change.

It doesn't sound intuitive but it could help.